# executing multiple select statements to pick a value in where condition using Case statement

Tags: case, teradata, where-clause

Case statement with select statement as loops in where condition

need to bring values by referring two tables. if the value doesn't exist in table a it has to refer the 2nd table

```
Sel * from Table A
where city = (case when (sel distinct city from Table A) is null 
then (sel city from Table B) end)
```

expected output is as shown below

```
Sel * from Table A
where City = 'XYZ'
```

if value is not present in `table A` it has to refer `Table B` statement and show the value in where condition

Comment: Your description is quite confusing, I don't understand what you want. Can you add some data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you need to be careful with here is to make sure you return a single value in your scalar sub-queries -- `(sel distinct city from Table A)` and `(sel city from Table B)`.  If you can always guarantee that then I think your query will work as is.

A safer way to do it is guarantee you always get one row.  Here's one option:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
WHERE City = (
  SELECT city
  FROM (
    -- Get all cities from TableA
    SELECT city, 1 AS table_priority
    FROM tableA

    UNION ALL

    -- Get all cities from TableB
    SELECT city, 2
    FROM tableB
  ) src
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY src.table_priority, src.city) = 1 -- Return one row
)
```

Comment: Yes, the `SELECT ... UNION ALL ... SELECT` will return a value from `TableB` if there is no value in `TableA`.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What is the `UNION ALL` doing, other than forcing you to qualify?  Wouldn't using `where tablea.city in  (select city from <first table> union select city from <second table>)` work?

Comment: According to the original post, he wants to have the equivalent of `WHERE city = 'xyz'` but keep the `if value is not in TableA then use value in TableB` logic, so I assumed he only wants to return a single city.  Hence the `QUALIFY`.